Continuous mixture distribution
I am currently working on the derivation of the negative binomial distribution as a result of a continuous mixture of Poisson and Gamma distribution for regression purposes.
To obtain the entire conditional distribution, one wants to integrat out the influence of the unobserved heterogeneity:
$$f(y_i \mid x_i) = \int_{0}^{\infty} h(y_i \mid x_i, \nu_i) \omega(\nu_i \mid x_i) \, d\nu_i
$$
which can e.g. be done if $\omega(\nu_i \mid x_i)$ is chosen to be a Gamma distribution, but there are other possibilities available too.
My question is what does that mean to integrate out the influence of a disturbance such as $\nu_i$? Is there a possibility to visualize a simple example of what is going on here?

Anything helpful in earlier questions like https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/479170/7224 - https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/433161/7224 - https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/525038/7224 - https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/569696/7224 ???
